# How can I implement angularJS without NuGet in a folder in MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a new folder named angularJS and I don't know how to implement it without using a NuGet Packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add reference of `angular.js` to your layout or any `cshtml` file you need.

Here is working sample without `NuGet Packages`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
 
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>
```